# "Enable the experimental WSL 2 based engine" not selectable

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2

I'm following these instructions to run my Docker Daemon on WSL 2 on Windows 10:

https://medium.com/@callback.insanity/upgrading-to-wsl-2-9883688fcfa5

But, when I try to Enable the experimental WSL 2 based engine, I cannot select the checkbox, as seen here:

[image]

I am running `Windows 10 build 1909`

The message here reads:

> (requires Win 10 build 19018+)

I am not on the fast track or Insider Preview program (and I don't want to be), but it is not clear to me at all if my build satisfies this requirement. I am running WSL 2 (and yes, it's pretty nice, aside from the fact that it doesn't seem to be working with Docker as I'd prefer).

Is the problem I'm facing that my Windows build version is too low, or is there something else I should try?

**Update:**
As pointed out in comments below, the **version number** of my Windows is different than the **build number**. I checked the build number by going into system information and seeing the my build number is 18362.

Comment: For newcomers it's worth noting that this now works on stable Docker Desktop (2.5.0.1) which can enable WSL 2 support on normal (non-insider) Win 10 version 1909 (build 18363) and even version 1903 (build 18362) - just make sure Windows is patched up to date & reboot after upgrading Docker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1909 is a lower number than 19018. Also, I think you *have* to be in the Insider Preview program at the moment to enable that option.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/

[image]

I'm in the same boat as you; I'm dying to use it as well, but don't want to join the Insider program, so I'm just trying to be patient, and wait it out.

Comment: That's true, but it looks like every Windows Preview build number is higher than every regular build number. It does not seem like there's a way to identify which build contains which preview features without auditing the Microsoft release announcements. Is that what's expected?

Comment: I think you are correct. I'll be accepting this answer shortly.

Comment: @GlenPierce TBH I'm not sure if there's a way to identify what's new in each Preview release; I haven't really been paying any attention to the Insider version. Too many other things to do in my TODO list to keep up with it, lol.

Comment: @GlenPierce BTW, I haven't tried this myself, and lord knows what could happen if it works ;), but being a bit of a hacker and liking to make things do what I'm not allowed to do, there are Object Enablers out there that might let you enable that box, and "see what happens". Not saying I recommend it, but if you like to tinker and take chances: https://geekdrop.com/x/oe

Comment: 1909 is not a build number. It's a version number that encodes the approximate release date (September 2019). Comparing it to a build number like 19018 is meaningless. Whatever conclusion you draw from this is equally meaningless.

Comment: @IInspectable Thing is, the screenshot literally shows "(requires Win 10 build 19018+)"  ....

Comment: Correct. It says *"build"*. So compare it against another build number. Comparing it against a version (like 1909) is still meaningless. Much like saying: 2 hours is lower than 42 gallons.

Comment: @IInspectable Gotcha, I see what your saying. I wonder why Docker chooses to compare builds then, rather than versions? Often-times a new build number can simply come from recompiling the exact same source.

Comment: @GlenPierce I'm curious now; what does your build say? Click the Start Menu and Type "Version" and hit enter, and it'll show you.

Comment: It uses a build number, because the feature was introduced in between versions. This is common practice with experimental or preview features.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this. Just install Docker Desktop Edge (early access to new features). Link: https://desktop.docker.com/win/edge/48173/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe

Install Windows 10, version 2004 or higher. **The Docker Desktop Edge release also supports Windows 10, version 1903 or higher.**

ref: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#prerequisites

In this way I can enable and use wsl2 with my docker desktop [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw8Ol.png)